# yum groupinstall "Development Libraries"

Tags: rhel, yum

I am looking at some configuration notes for a CentOS, but I am configuring a Redhat machine. I am not clear:

1. What the below commands install?
2. Why one might install these?
3. Are these applicable to a RedHat installation?

```
    yum groupinstall  "Development Libraries"
    yum groupinstall  "Development Tools"
    yum groupinstall  "Server Configuration Tools"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group install just installs some group of packages (= all packages in a group). This can be useful when you want to install gnome desktop, and instead of typing `yum install gnome-session nautilus gdm <and many more>` you can just run something like `yum groupinstall "GNOME desktop"`. For servers I don't see any reason to use groupinstall and don't recommend it: don't install anything you don't really need. Use `yum install <package>` to install something you really want.

And, to check what's being installed with `groupinstall` use `groupinfo`: `yum groupinfo  "Development Libraries"`. To get list of all available groups run `yum grouplist`.